# How to programmatically change the state of a stateful widget at run time?

Tags: flutter

I'm building a custom Flutter widget to support a grouped list of radio buttons, displayed as a group of buttons. Only one button can be selected in the group, and it is highlighted to show its selected state.

From a user perspective, clicking on a button to make it the current selection is straightforward.

However, I have another situation where I want to programmatically change the selected button, but I can't find a way of exposing a property at the widget level that would allow me to change the state.

I had thought about storing the 'state' object at the widget level within an overridden 'createState' method.

Any suggestions?

Comment: ig you are looking for state-mangement solution

Comment: see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Radio-class.html - it has an example where at line #58 the state of radio group is changed

Answer (score 0):

Actually i could not understand your purpose clearly but i hope this code helps you:

```
import 'package:amlakdaran/core/theme.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomCheckBox extends StatefulWidget {
  List<String> items;
  List<String>? selectedItem;
  Function(List<String> items) selectionCallBack;

  CustomCheckBox(this.items, this.selectionCallBack, {this.selectedItem});

  @override
  State<CustomCheckBox> createState() => _CustomCheckBoxState();
}

class _CustomCheckBoxState extends State<CustomCheckBox> {
  List<String> selectedItems = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if(widget.selectedItem!=null) {
      selectedItems=widget.selectedItem!;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: Wrap(
        children: [
            for (var item in widget.items) getBody(item)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getBody(item) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 2),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          if (selectedItems.contains(item)) {
            selectedItems.remove(item);
          } else {
            selectedItems.add(item);
          }
          setState(
            () {},
          );
          widget.selectionCallBack(selectedItems);
        },
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2, horizontal: 7),
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
              color: selectedItems.contains(item)
                  ? AppColors.yellow
                  : Colors.white,
              border: Border.all(
                  color: selectedItems.contains(item)
                      ? AppColors.yellow
                      : Colors.grey)),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              if (selectedItems.contains(item))
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.check,
                    size: 15,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              Text(
                item,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14,
                  color: selectedItems.contains(item)
                      ? Colors.white
                      : Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The code is my personal checkbox and i usually use it in my projects. And Call it in this way:

```
 CustomCheckBox(
          [],//your items
          (items) {
            //selected items
          },
          selectedItem: [],//if you have default items 

        ),
```

Also you can use this package [grouped_buttons](https://pub.dev/packages/grouped_buttons). The code is some thing like this:

```
List<String> _checked = ["A", "B"];
CheckboxGroup(
  orientation: GroupedButtonsOrientation.HORIZONTAL,
  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
  onSelected: (List selected) => setState((){
    _checked = selected;
  }),
  labels: <String>[
    "A",
    "B",
  ],
  checked: _checked,
  itemBuilder: (Checkbox cb, Text txt, int i){
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Icon(Icons.polymer),
        cb,
        txt,
      ],
    );
  },
);
```